# Class DistributedFileSytem not found in PIG Program

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, apache-pig

Im getting below exception when i try to run sample PIG program in eclipse.

Can someone suggest solution

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DistributedFileSystem
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:162)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:117)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:240)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:215)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:196)
    at testpackage.TestClass.testName(TestClass.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 30 more
```

I have configured `HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_HDFS_HOME` correctly in Eclipse `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed!!

I just updated hadoop conf directory in Eclipse buildpath